# mysql query does not showing multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

my database sample is like this

```
database:test
table:test

id  name  password   message  active
1   test  testpass   testmsg   no
2   test2 testtest   testmsg2  no
```

and when i run sql query and show it in php it just gives one result.
php part was,

```
$a=mysqli_query($con,"select name from test where active='no'");
$b=mysqli_fetch_array($a);
print_r($b);
```

and it showed only the first record

```
test
```

can anybody please suggest me,where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a while loop to iterate over all the records

```
$a=mysqli_query($con,"select name from test where active='no'");
while($b=mysqli_fetch_array($a))
print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is desired behavior of PHP. You should fetch the rows in loop, like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select name from test where active='no'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($b);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the result using loop :

```
$b = mysql_fetch_array($query)

foreach($b as $b)
{
  echo $b[];
]
```